# Why does an object declared in a class only allow a non-parameter constructor?

Tags: c++

When you construct a class, it is my understanding that variables declared always instantiates via the default-constructor and you cannot instantiate via calling a constructor which takes parameters.

ex this is allowed:

```
class A
{
    B my_B;
}
```

But this isn't:

```
class A
{
     B my_B(param);
}
```

What is the reason for this rule? In the first example as far as I know it will still call a custom constructor you write, just one which doesn't take in values.

Comment: You may write class A
{
     B my_B{param};
};

Comment: You can specify parameters in `A`'s constructor like `class A { B my_B; A() : my_B(42) {} };`.

Comment: Note: you are trying to use a specific construct (added in C++11) called *default member initialiser*. The way class members are initialised in C++ is non-trivial and you should learn about this topic from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/7976805) to avoid surprises.